# How to compare two Carbon Timestamps?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have two timestamps, edited_at which I created and created_at (Laravel's)... 
In database, both have type timestamp and default value 0000-00-00 00:00:00... But

`var_dump(edited_at variable)` is giving string. While `var_dump(created_at variable)` is object/Carbon. What is wrong with these timestamps?

I have to compare both after converting into integer using format('U'). I can only call this method on Carbon Object. How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly do you want to compare? do you want to know which is older/newer?

Comment: yes, I want to campare older/newer

Comment: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison

Answer (score 275, accepted):

First, Eloquent automatically converts it's timestamps (`created_at`, `updated_at`) into carbon objects. You could just use `updated_at` to get that nice feature, or specify `edited_at` in your model in the `$dates` property:

```
protected $dates = ['edited_at'];
```

---

Now back to your actual question. Carbon has a bunch of comparison functions:

- `eq()` equals
- `ne()` not equals
- `gt()` greater than
- `gte()` greater than or equals
- `lt()` less than
- `lte()` less than or equals

Usage:

```
if($model->edited_at->gt($model->created_at)){
    // edited at is newer than created at
}
```

Comment: How can I compare the dates only and not the time?

Comment: @geckob The easiest is probably to do `$date1->toDateString() == $date2->toDateString()`

Comment: I am testing and it is possible to use the comparison operators to compare Carbon objects. Is it a new feature?

Comment: When using this, remember to handle nullable timestamps. Laravel will just convert the SQL `null` into a PHP `null` instead of a Carbon object, and you'll get `call to a member function lt() on null`.

Comment: you should use $some_cabron_date->endOfDay() or $some_cabron_date->startOfDay() with that functions to the desired operation

Comment: @lukasgeiter or `$date->isSameAs(now())`

Comment: So, you can use the normal PHP operators to compare Carbon and DateTime dates? @okdewit

Answer (score 55):

Carbon has a bunch of comparison functions **with mnemonic names**:

- equalTo()
- notEqualTo()
- greaterThan()
- greaterThanOrEqualTo()
- lessThan()
- lessThanOrEqualTo()

Usage:

```
 if($model->edited_at->greaterThan($model->created_at)){
     // edited at is newer than created at
 }
```

> Valid for nesbot/carbon 1.36.2

if you are not sure what Carbon version you are on, run this

```
$composer show "nesbot/carbon"
```

documentation:  https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison

Answer (score 4):

First, convert the timestamp using the built-in eloquent functionality, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29684354/3904384).

Then you can just use Carbon's `min()` or `max()` function for comparison.  For example:

`$dt1 = Carbon::create(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
$dt2 = Carbon::create(2014, 1, 30, 0, 0, 0);
echo $dt1->min($dt2);`

This will `echo` the lesser of the two dates, which in this case is `$dt1`.

See http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 4):

This is how I am comparing 2 dates, **now()** and a date from the table

```
@if (\Carbon\Carbon::now()->lte($item->client->event_date_from))
    .....
    .....
@endif
```

Should work just right.
I have used the comparison functions provided by Carbon.