# Carbon diffForHumans only when difference is greater than 0

Tags: php, time, php-carbon

in our application, we want to show offers like `valid for 5 hours`, `valid for 4 hours` and so on till the offer expires, now problem is, even when the offer period expired, it shows `valid for 1 hour` and so on, this is how we are implementing `carbon's` `diffForHumans()`

```
function time_diff($type = null, $time = null)
{
   if(is_null($type) || is_null($time))
   {
      return 'moments ago';
   }
   else
   {
      $ist_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
      $ist_now = Carbon::now('Asia/Kolkata');
      return $ist_time->diffForHumans($ist_now, true);
   }
 }
```

**what we expect**

as soon as the offered is expired, we can show `expired` or we can hide it from the main page

**what we want to know**

how to know if `time difference is > 0`

Comment: `if ($ist_time < $ist_now) do diff human else return 'expired';`

Comment: Check how to compare the two times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684111/how-to-compare-two-carbon-timestamps