# Retrive records where updated_at is older than created_at with 2 hours in Laravel (eloquent)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I want to count records where updated_at is 2 hours older than created_at.

### Code

```
$teLang = $kentekens->where('updated_at', '>', 'created_at'->subHours(2));
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work because subHours(2) is for carbon but hopefully you get the idea.

### View

```
<h1>{{ $teLang->count() }}</h1>
```

### Controller

```
public function create() {
        $kentekens = Kenteken::latest()
            ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())
            ->get();

        $teLang = $kentekens->where('updated_at', '>', 'created_at'->subHours(2));

        return view('layouts.dashboard', compact('kentekens', 'teLang'));
    }
```

anyone know how?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29684354/4875631) help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$kentekens->whereRaw('`updated_at` > DATE_ADD(`created_at`, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)');
```

SQL:

```
select `id` from `tablename` where `updated_at` > DATE_ADD(`created_at`, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`filter()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-filter) method. Using your code logic:

```
$teLang = $kentekens->filter(function($i) {
    return $i->updated_at->gt($i->created_at->subHours(2));
});
```

Using this statement "where updated_at is 2 hours older than created_at":

```
$teLang = $kentekens->filter(function($i) {
    return $i->updated_at->lt($i->created_at->subHours(2));
});
```

Comment: Using the gt returns a row that shouldn't be included where 'created_at' =  2018-01-24 16:59:12 and 'updated_at' = 2018-01-24 17:44:32. This shouldn't be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe so?

```
public function create() {
    $kentekens = Kenteken::latest()
        ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())
        ->get();
    $cr = Carbon::create($kentekens->created_at);
    $teLang = $kentekens->where('updated_at', '>', $cr->addHours(2));

    return view('layouts.dashboard', compact('kentekens', 'teLang'));
}
```