# How to compare carbon date in laravel?

Tags: laravel, date, compare, php-carbon

I try to check if today is the 3 days after the registration day or not, so i compare today date with the registration date plus 3 days. But i think my code is not working, this is my code:

```
$get_tanggal_permohonan = DB::table('data_pemohon')->select('tanggal_permohonan')->where('noper', $noper)->first();
$tanggal_permohonan     = $get_tanggal_permohonan->tanggal_permohonan;
$Dday       = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($tanggal_permohonan);
$today      = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString();
$today      = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date);

if($today < $Dday->subDays(3)){
    echo "not the time to come";
}else{
    echo "time to come"
}
```

I have no idea to solve this error, help me please. Thank you.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: The latest version

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29684354/2065215 i think this is the answer to your question.

Comment: Does it have to be exactly 3 days after or just 3 or more days after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DiffInDays()`

```
if( $Dday->diffInDays($today) > 3){
    echo "not the time to come";
}else{
    echo "time to come"
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work as the diffInDays is an absolute value, ie it may be in 3 days time or 3 days may have elapsed and it will give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Question already anwsered here [How to compare two Carbon Timestamps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684111/how-to-compare-two-carbon-timestamps)

```
if (Carbon::parse($date)->gt(Carbon::now()))
```

for more http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison

Comment: The question asks for a 3 day limit, not just greater than

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [isSameDay()](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) method and the Laravel [today()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-today) helper function:

```
$get_tanggal_permohonan = DB::table('data_pemohon')->select('tanggal_permohonan')->where('noper', $noper)->first();
$tanggal_permohonan = $get_tanggal_permohonan->tanggal_permohonan;
$Dday = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($tanggal_permohonan);

if ($Dday->addDays(3)->isSameDay(today())) {
    echo "not the time to come";
} else {
    echo "time to come";
}
```