# How to count calculate the remaining time years using Carbon Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I have a table name user . in user have filed colomn 'date' .

in this colomn field 'date' have data like this

```
 users table 

id | name | email | date |

1  | jhon | a@gmail.com |  2021-06-07 |

2  | phil | b@gmail.com | 2020-06-07 |
```

i want to showed data where 'date' is year is less than 1 year from now.

from this table just show :

> 2  | phil | b@gmail.com | 2020-06-07 |

because this date is less than 1 year . i am using laravel .

Comment: is your date column retrieved as a carbon ?

Comment: The answer is already answered here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684111/how-to-compare-two-carbon-timestamps
And use gt() carbon function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show users who have "date" that is less than a year from now. You can write a query very easily for that.

```
$users = User::whereBetween('date', [now(), now()->addYear()])->get();
```

This will filter down the results who have "date" values between **now** and a year from now. **now** is a helper function that returns a carbon date instance.

Comment: its solved ,but how if i need to years ? i just add  now()->addYear(2) . like that ?

Comment: @AdhikMulat yes, exactly like that. If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to get users which their date field are less than one year from now:

```
User::query()->where('date', '<', Carbon::now()->subYear())->get();
```

Comment: Class 'Carbon' not found .   i used use Carbon; , but still like that

Comment: i solved abaout carbon not found . now my problem ,this displayed data is wrong