# Carbon::parse get just date

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I have a date stored as follows:

```
$user->password_expiry_dt

Carbon @1573228178 {#647 ▼
    date: 2019-11-08 15:49:38.0 UTC (+00:00)
}
```

I want to check if its expired without using the timestamp so currently i'm doing this:

```
Carbon::parse($user->password_expiry_dt)->hour(0)->minute(0)->second(0) <= Carbon::today()
```

Is there an easier or more elegant way to get the date without the timestamp as follows without having to chain all these extra setters?

```
2019-11-08 00:00:00.0
```

Comment: why not just set the date format for in the model? or overwrite the getter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Carbon::parse($user->password_expiry_dt)->startOfDay()` will do it for you

Comment: This situation is similar, not equal, but similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684111/how-to-compare-two-carbon-timestamps/29684354